# JavaScript function to generate dropdowns / remove dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add and remove dropdown `<select>`s to a form on a button click.  This is the code I have currently.  I could have sworn I had this working last night, but when I went to work some more on my project this morning, the dropdowns wouldn't add / remove correctly.

```
function DropDowns(){
    this.counter = 0;
    this.addDropdown = function (divname) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var html = '<select name="cookie' + this.counter + '">', i;

        for (i = 0; i < cookies_drop.length; i++) {
           html += "<option value='" + cookies_drop[i] + "'>" + cookies_drop[i] + "</option>"
        }
        html += '</select>';
        newDiv.innerHTML = html;
        document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newDiv);

        this.counter++;
    }

    this.remDropdown = function() {
        $('#dropdowns-container').find('div:last').remove();
        this.counter--;
    }
}

var dropsTest = new DropDowns();
```

HTML:

```
<form action='' method=post id="dropdowns-container">

    <button id="add_cookie" type="button" onclick="dropsTest.addDropdown('dropdowns-container');">add cookie</button>
    <button id="rem_cookie" type="button" onclick="dropsTest.remDropdown();">remove cookie</button>

<input name="cookies" type=submit value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: What's `cookies_drop`?

Comment: what do you mean by "correctly"?   What behavior are you seeing?   What is "cookies_drop"?   you're incrementing  "counter", but you defined "this.counter".  Also, dropTest should be undefined, since you're not doing  "var dropTest = new DropDowns();"

In fact, it's probably the missing "new" that's messing you up, but your counter logic will fail because of the missing "this"'s

Comment: Sorry, I'll clear up the questions.  cookies_drop is an array.  It is declared on a php page where a php array "converted" to cookies_drop using json_encode.  The cookies_drop array populates correctly currently.  The behavior I am seeing is that when I click the "add cookie" button no new dropdowns are added to the form.  Thank you for pointing out the "this.counter" issue, I will update my code and see how it goes.

Comment: I have added the changes suggested and updated the code in the OP now.  The result is the same, clicking the "add cookie" button does not add a new dropdown still.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle with your code and stubbed out cookies_drop and it worked:  https://jsfiddle.net/t4k5kheq/  are you seeing any errors in the console?  Also, I don't see the value of the counter.   You're not using it to select the removing select.  and if you keep clicking rem_cookie the value will go negative.

Comment: @RayWadkins JSFiddle needs jQuery for the remove-button to work.

Comment: @Emil yeah, I noticed that after I put the link.

Comment: It's working just fine. check this plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/B9Je9Cm8ddvzaou16v9V?p=preview
I guess the problem is in the array coming from php.
Can you add the php code ?

Comment: @Csw so did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can only figure out the main problem may be on the server side when you  create the cookies_drop variable using json_encode.

Other problems may reside in:

1. A test on the parameter of addDropdown function is suggested to check if it's valid
2. In the function remDropdown the decrement of the counter variable must be done only if the element is actually removed
3. You mixed jQuery and javaScript
4. Instead of using directly the createElement, making the code more simple and readable, you used the innerHTML property.

So, my snippet is:

```js
// I assume you used something like:
// var cookies_drop = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>' );

var cookies_drop = [{text: "Text1", val: "Value1"},
                    {text: "Text2", val: "Value2"},
                    {text: "Text3", val: "Value3"}];

function DropDowns() {
  this.counter = 0;
  this.addDropdown = function (divname) {
    var divEle = document.querySelectorAll('form[id=' + divname + ']');
    if (divEle.length != 1) {
      return; // error
    }

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    var newSelect = document.createElement('select');
    newSelect.name = 'cookie' + this.counter;
    newDiv.appendChild(newSelect);

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies_drop.length; i++) {
      var newOption = document.createElement('option');
      newOption.value = cookies_drop[i].val;
      newOption.text = cookies_drop[i].text;
      newSelect.appendChild(newOption);
    }
    divEle[0].appendChild(newDiv);
    this.counter++;
  }

  this.remDropdown = function () {
    var lastDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#dropdowns-container div:last-child');
    if (lastDiv.length == 1) {
      lastDiv[0].parentNode.removeChild(lastDiv[0]);
      this.counter--;
    }
  }
}
var dropsTest = new DropDowns();
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="dropdowns-container">
    <button id="add_cookie" type="button" onclick="dropsTest.addDropdown('dropdowns-container');">add cookie</button>
    <button id="rem_cookie" type="button" onclick="dropsTest.remDropdown();">remove cookie</button>
    <input name="cookies" type=submit value="submit">
</form>
```